# Usage of plural nouns with and without 'the'

Tags: articles, definite-article, singular-vs-plural

Can I use the plural nouns in the given sentences with and without **the**. What difference in meaning does **the** create in the sentences? And as an English speaker which one sounds best to your ears?

1. John, I have been to many countries in my life. I can tell you one thing that (**the**) people in America are politically very aware.
2. **(The)** students at this school are diligent, intelligent and smart.

As an ESL learner it confuses me a lot because I have seen sentences like these are used both with and without **the**. And I can't figure it out. Could anyone please explain?

My probelms begin when nouns with plural from come before prepositions like -(**the**) people in America, (**the**) teachers at this scool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, the meaning stays the same, with or without *the*.

The meaning of "people in America are politically aware" is: *the majority of people in America are politically aware" or "all typical Americans are politically aware."

The literal meaning of "the people in America are politically aware" is: *all of the people in America are politically aware.*

However, these kinds of statements are often meant non-literally; they are exaggerations.  That is, the intended meaning is often "most of the people in America..." or "virtually all of the people..." or "all of the typical people..."